# Why do tables get out of sync over time when Write Consistency ALL is used?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Iam running a cassandra 3.11.4 cluster with 1 data center, 2 racks and 11 nodes. My keyspaces and the tables are set to replication 2. I use the Prometheus-Grafana-Combo to monitor the cluster.

Observation: During (massive) inserts using Write-Consistency Level ALL (i.e. 2 nodes) the affected tables/nodes get slowly out of sync (worst case on one node: from 100% to 83% within 6 hours). My expectation is that this could only happen if I use ANY (or anything less than my replication factor).

I would really like to understand this behaviour.

What is also interesting: If I dare to use write consistency ANY I get exactly that- and even though all nodes are online Cassandra does not even seem attempt to write to all nodes. In any case (ANY or ALL) if have to perform incremental repairs.

Comment: how do you define and measure "out of sync" ?

Comment: I use "Cassandra Exporter" to export metrics of Cassandra to Prometheus/Grafana ([https://github.com/criteo/cassandra_exporter]). And exemplary entry would be `cassandra_stats{cluster="MyCluster",datacenter="datacenter1",instance="<NodeIP>:8050",job="cassandra",keyspace="somekeyspace",name="org:apache:cassandra:metrics:table:somekeyspace:mytable:percentrepaired:value",table="mytable"}`

Alternatively I can also reproduce these decreasing numbers by using `nodetool info`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your expectation is correct: Writes, regardless of what the consistency-level is (ALL or ONE or ANY or whatever), do make every attempt to write to **all** replicas. The different write-consistency levels only differ on when "success" is reported to the client: ALL waits until all writes were done, while ONE waits for just one (and does the other ones in the background). So unless one of your nodes goes down, or severely overloaded, none of the writes should be missing on any of the nodes, and there should be zero inconsistencies. The "hinted handoff" feature makes inconsistencies even less likely (if one node is temporarily down, other nodes save for it the writes it missed, and replay them later).

I think your only problem is that you're misinterpreting what the "percentrepaired" statistic means. The "percentrepaired" metric is used by **incremental repair**. In incremental repair, data on disk is split between "repaired" data (data that already went through a repair process) and "unrepaired" data - new data that still did not yes pass through repair. This does not mean that the new data is inconsistent or differs between nodes - it just that nobody checked that yet! To mark this new data "repaired" you'd need to run an (incremental) repair - it will realize the data does **not** differ between nodes, and mark it as "repaired".